# Indesign: apply stroke to image contents, not image box

Tags: adobe-indesign, images, stroke

I have an image with a transparent background, which I'd like to apply a stroke to. The issue is, any time I apply a stroke to the image it applies to the image box and not the image shape itself.

Can InDesign recognize the shape of the transparent image and apply the stroke to that?

Below is the unwanted effect. I'd like the stroke to follow the people:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Never mind, I figured it out.

- Object > Clipping Path > Options
- Change Type to Alpha Channel

[image]

- Object > Clipping Path > Convert Clipping Path to Frame
- Apply effects

[image]

The downside I see to this method is that it only applies the stroke along the outer edge of the image. For my current project, this is fine, but could be an issue for other uses.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind that the stroke around the image contents is raster and not vector, you can simply apply an *effect*.

I place my beautiful artwork with transparent background on top of a background like this:

[image]

I can then select the image and use *Object > Effects > Outer Glow* with the following settings:

[image]

And get a result like this:

[image]